# How to retry gradle connectedAndroidTest after specific exception

Tags: android, testing, gradle

I 'm running instrumentation tests via `gradlew connectedAndroidTest` on CircleCI.

Tests on android-22 emulator occasionally (once in about 15 times) failed because of `ShellCommandUnresponsiveException`.

Finally, I gave up solving this error and decided to retry test if fail with this exception.

Does anyone know how to do this?